# Explanation of Reverse function in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm learning python and the "teacher" (a youtube channel) gives this function to revert the characters of a given array.
I can't understand how the function reverts the characters.

```
1    alfa = "hello"
2    def reverser(string):
3        index = (len(string) -1) 
4        new_string = ""
5        while index >= 0:
6            new_string += string[index]
7            index -= 1
8        print(new_string)
9    
10    reverser(alfa)
```

**Line 3**: I know `len` returns the number of `"hello"` in this case. That `-1` confuses me. Is it used to return the last character or to subtract the LEN result? why?

**Line 4**: ok we are creating a new `string`.

**Line 6**: No ideas...

**Line 7**: No ideas again...

I need help to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to SO Mauro. Thanks for taking the time to write your understanding of the code. I hope you stick with learning `Python`

Comment: If David the third's answer is satisfactory and worked for you be she to give him the green checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3: You are getting the length of `string` and subtracting 1 from it. The reason for this is the way indexing works in python. When using indexing in python, the first element is at position 0, and `len` returns the length of the string. Subtracting one from it makes it consistent with the way indexing works.

Line 6: You are appending the character in `string` at `index` to `new_string`.

Line 7: `index` will be decremented by one, meaning it's value will be one less than before in order to use the character before the last one used in the string.

Comment: It may be worth explaining why we subtract 1 from the length of string. As taking the len starts counting at 1 but in coding we use zero indexing - so the 5th letter is indexed as 4.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer!
So in the loop it start reading the characters from the last one (given by the len) and subtracting 1 by 1 until the loop is not True anymore. Right?